# How to trigger on-premise jenkins job from VSTS using service hook

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, azure-devops

My source code is present in VSTS(cloud) and Jenkins job in the on-premise server(don't have public IP). I would like to implement Continuous integration.

I have a one local build agent. VSTS build definition able to trigger Jenkins job using the agent. But I don't want to create a job. So how to trigger Jenkins job using service hooks.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to add local jenkins server to service hook.

Since the local jenkins server (such as http://localhost:8080 or http://{ip}:8080) can not accessed by public network, VSTS can not access to your local jenkins neither. You should make sure the jenkin url is reachable for public network if you need to use service hook.

And if you want to trigger Jenkins build for the event that VSTS **build completed**, you can add [Jenkins Queue Job task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/jenkins-queue-job) the the end of the VSTS build. Detail configuration for this task as below:

Add jenkins service endpoint by clicking the New button -> Input jenkin URL, username and password -> not necessary to verify connection since the public network can't reached -> OK -> input jenkin job name.

[image]

[image]

Now when the VSTS build pervious tasks are succeed, then jenkins job is triggered.

**Note:** You should queue the VSTS build by private agent on the same machine where jenkins server installed.